# WPF MetroWindow Min Max Close background when app loses focus

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm working on an WPF app that uses MahApps MetroWindow as the mainwindow. I used styling on the Minimize / Maximize and Close buttons that are build in the MetroWindow. Style currently looks as following: (maximize and close style are similar)

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.WindowMinButtonStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="35"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                    Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                    Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Padding"
                    Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid x:Name="grid"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                              RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                              Opacity="0.75" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                     Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter"
                                        Property="Opacity"
                                        Value="1" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                     Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter"
                                        Property="Opacity"
                                        Value=".5" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                     Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                        Value="#ADADAD" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Controls:MetroWindow.WindowMinButtonStyle>
```

The style itself works as expected but I miss one thing:

- When the application loses focus i want to set the background of those buttons to grayed out just like the rest of the application. Currently the buttons are still the bound to the resource `PrimaryHueMidBrush`.

I though i could change the background of the buttons in this event but I can't find the min max close buttons in the MetroWindow.

```cs
private void Window_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SolidColorBrush gray = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
            StatusBar.Background = gray;
        }

        private void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StatusBar.Background = (SolidColorBrush)FindResource("PrimaryHueMidBrush");
        }
```

Is there a way to set the background of those buttons when the application loses focus (window_deactivated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `DataTrigger` to the `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` element in your `Style` that binds to the `Active` property of the parent window:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
             Value="False">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Haha i wanted to do that but i had to little reputation to do that.. Thanks again anyway!